# What to do if you are unintentionaly subject of favoritism?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, project-management, relationships, teamwork

I have the following situation at work. I am part of a team with people having different background age-wise and business wise. Since the beginning of the project It happened so that I took the role of a driver. I did quite a good job, but the project manager started to rely so much on me and favour me so much before the other members of the team that I am afraid this will lead me eventually into a conflict with the rest of the team. The situation is made worse by the fact that the other experienced developer on the team is slacking off (which I don't have problem with I don't care really how much effort he is putting in. I always look only in my plate.) and the other developer is junior. The team consists of two other very senior resources which act more as subject matter experts than real developers. My main issue is that the PO has started to heavily favour me. What can I do so that at one point I take the credit for my good work and on the other hand not get into trouble with my colleagues ?

Comment: " is inclining more of the Nepotism side" What does that mean?

Comment: "took the role of a driver"?  What does that mean?

Comment: Also, having a clearer idea fo the ways in which the PO is showing favoritism would help.

Comment: @FooTheBar sory, wrong usage of words. English is not my native language. I will correct

Comment: @BenBarden look into social interaction styles. But in general it means someone that takes initiative more or less.

Comment: @Pesho I think the word you may be looking for is "leader" or "team lead" -- "I took the role of a leader" or "I took the role of a team lead" would be understood.

Comment: I don't see this as a clear of favoritism. A project manager's job is to get the project done well and on time. If you have one resource out of many that can carry the project and achieve those goals, then mission accomplished give all of the work to that resource. While I would like to think the project manager also would think about effective resource management, this isn't necessarily their job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a few golden rules for the workplace:

- Do good work.
- Ask questions when things aren't clear. Make sure you're getting clarification from the right person (usually, your boss).
- Respect others.

I find that when I do these things, problems like favoritism have a way of taking care of themselves. Or, at least, you have a safety net to fall back on when conflict does actually happen.

Worrying about what your coworkers will think, or trying to pre-plan to avoid conflict can quickly become unhealthy if doing so distracts you from these golden rules. Keep in mind: **you can't control other people.** No matter what you do, others may dislike you for it. So, don't allow yourself to be consumed with worrying about whether or not other people will find something to dislike about you, because there's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

If the project manager is favoring you and relying on you more than your colleagues, this is usually an indication that you are doing good work and are considered more reliable than them.  Continue to do the good work that you have been doing and don't worry about what your colleagues may think.

If any conflict arises due to your doing your job well, it would be unprofessional behavior on the part of your colleagues.  Don't "dumb down" your effort and productivity simply because you feel that your colleagues may be jealous and start to cause problems.